# Why the autocomplete widget doesn't work if the text is NOT empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How is ti possible that the code below show the array ONLY if the text is empty... It should show the list during the typing NOT when the text is empty.

STEPS:

1. Focus on text
2. type a text, like 'abc' (this text returns an array doing the ajax call)
3. nothing happen
4. delete 'abc' and i see the array correctly.

   ```
   $('#titolare').keyup(function(){
     var titolare = $.trim($('#titolare').val());

     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "page.php",
       data: { titolare: titolare },
       success: function(msg){          
         var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);

         if (obj.result){
           var tit   = obj.titolare
             , tit_a = [];            

           $.each (tit, function (a) {              
             tit_a[a] = { titolare: tit[a].titolare, cod_fis: tit[a].cod_fis };
           });         

               $("#titolare").autocomplete({
             minLength: 0,         
             source: tit_a,
                   focus: function( event, ui ) {             
                       $("#titolare").val(ui.item.titolare);
                       return false;
                   },
                   select: function( event, ui ) {            
                       $("#titolare").val(ui.item.titolare);
                       return false;
                   }
               })
               .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function(ul, item) {          
                   return $( "<li></li>" )
                       .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                       .append( "<a>" + item.titolare + "<br />("+ item.cod_fis +")</a>")
                       .appendTo( ul );
               };            

         }                                             
       }
     });        
   });
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want to use `keyUp` function. You can give url as the source like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#titolare" ).autocomplete({
             source: "page.php",                }
             focus: function( event, ui ) {             
                        $("#titolare").val(ui.item.titolare);
                        return false;
                    },
                    select: function( event, ui ) {            
                        $("#titolare").val(ui.item.titolare);
                        return false;
                    }
    }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function(ul, item) {          
                    return $( "<li></li>" )
                        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                        .append( "<a>" + item.titolare + "<br />("+ item.cod_fis +")</a>")
                        .appendTo( ul );
                };  
});
```

And in your page.php you can return relavant `JSON` object list.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote

Answer (score 1):

You can use the autocomplete widget in `#titolare` (without using the `keyup` listener) setting the `source` attribute to a function that would do both the ajax call and data transformation you need(and now you try to do it using the `keyup` method).

Something like:

```
$("#titolare").autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,         
      source: function(request, response){
          // ajax call and any data transformation here...
      },
      focus: function( event, ui ) {             
         $("#titolare").val(ui.item.titolare);
         return false;
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {            
         $("#titolare").val(ui.item.titolare);
         return false;
         }
 })
 ...
```

Have a look [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp).